# How to set the underline color of the edit text in xamarin android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I want to display the underline color of the edit text in xamarin android. How can I do this.

Here is my code

```
_editText = new EditText(Activity);
_editText.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.border);
_editText.SetTextColor(_black);
_editText.SetHintTextColor(_black);
_editText.Hint = "Please enter the Title";
_editText.LayoutParameters = new TableRow.LayoutParams(150, TableRow.LayoutParams.FillParent, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

From the Sdk version 21 (aka Lollipop) and above you should use `BackgroundTinList` property, for lower sdk's use `Background.SetColorFilter` method. For instance

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        var layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        var editText = new EditText(this)
        {
            LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent)           
        };

        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
        {
            editText.BackgroundTintList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(Color.Green);
        }
        else
        {
            editText.Background.SetColorFilter(Color.Green, PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
        }

        layout.AddView(editText);

        SetContentView(layout);
    }
}
```

Outcome:

[image]

Comment: My edit text is contained in a table row, after using your code the background color of the column is changed, I want to display the underline color of the edit text

Comment: This doesn't sound right. You will need to provide more code. Also you should replace the `FillParent` option that you're using for the `LayoutParameters` with `MatchParent`, as `FillParent` is obsolete/deprecated